# How to handle a random popup while executing Selenium Script?

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I'm executing a Selenium script, and randomly a popup appears which is about a survey one. I'm not sure when this would appear and the scripts are failing because of this. So please help me if anyone experienced the similar behavior and how did they resolve it. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Typically these are there to make it harder to navigate through the website through automation. That said, it may or may not be possible to cirumnavigate it. It is hard to answer without the webpage. I would suggest looking for what is causing this popup to be triggered and try to deactivate it by sending Javascript through Selenium